# $a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n}{\sqrt{a_n^2+1}}$. Find $a_n$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given $\{a_n\}$: $a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n}{\sqrt{a_n^2+1}}$, $a_1=1$.

Find $a_n$ like a function of $n$.

My trying.

Let $a_n=\tan\alpha_n$, where $\alpha_n\in\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$.

Hence, $a_{n+1}=\sin\alpha_n$ and what is the rest?

Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hint:  write it as $\;\cfrac{1}{a_{n+1}^2}=\cfrac{1}{a_{n}^2} + 1\,$.

Comment: It's beautiful!

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Thanks. I actually started by looking at $a_{n+1}=1 / \sqrt{1+(1/a_n)^2}$ then I "saw" it. Some times, rewriting an expression such that a variable occurs in *fewer* places can be telling.

Answer (score 10):

Note  that $${ a }_{ 2 }=\frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { 2 }  } \\ { a }_{ 3 }=\frac { \frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { 2 }  }  }{ \sqrt { \frac { 3 }{ 2 }  }  } =\frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { 3 }  } \\ { a }_{ 4 }=\frac { \frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { 3 }  }  }{ \sqrt { \frac { 4 }{ 3 }  }  } =\frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { 4 }  }
$$

---

so $$\\ { a }_{ n }=\frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { n }  } \\ $$

Answer (score 3):

Squaring gives,

$$a_{n+1}^2=\frac{a_n^2}{1+a_n^2}$$

Let $b_n=a_n^2$ then we have,

$$b_{n+1}=\frac{b_{n}}{1+b_{n}}$$

$$=\frac{1+b_n-1}{1+b_n}$$

$$=1-\frac{1}{1+b_n}$$

$$=1-\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}$$

$$=\frac{b_{n}-b_{n+1}}{b_{n}}$$

And hence,

$$\frac{b_{n}-b_{n+1}}{b_{n}b_{n+1}}=1$$

Thus,

$$\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \frac{b_{n}-b_{n+1}}{b_{n}b_{n+1}}=N-1$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \left(\frac{1}{b_{n+1}}-\frac{1}{b_{n}} \right)=N-1$$

$$\frac{1}{b_{N}}-\frac{1}{b_1}=N-1$$

$$b_{N}=\frac{1}{N-1+1}$$

$$a_{N}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{N-1+1}}$$

$$a_{N}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}$$